# Is there a way to generate a HOTP with time limitation?

Tags: algorithm, passwords, verification, one-time-password, totp

For example, I want to get a HOTP that can only be used in 10 minutes.

Not TOTP cause it's possible that when users get the code there are only 10 seconds left.

Comment: And if it's possible I want to achieve this only by using algorithm but a storage.

Comment: You might be able to find OTP/HOTP generators on GitHub or other sources. What is the specific issue that you're facing?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I know how to create a one-time password, but I don't know how to make sure that this password I created can only be used in next 10 minutes. I wonder that may I achieve this by pure algorithm solution without store the time in somewhere.

Comment: TOTP uses time as a param to generate different password each period, but it can be imagined that, if I generated a TOTP at the end of one period, this password can only be used in a few seconds. I hope my password can be used in 10 minutes every time it is created.

Comment: Set the period to 1 minute, and then accept as valid any TOTP that's been generated in the last 10 periods. That means a newly generated code is valid for somewhere between 9 and 10 minutes. Note, this reduces the space of the code smaller by a factor of 10, so you might want to add an extra digit to the code to compensate.

Comment: @PaulHankin That’s make sense! Thanks! All I need is to check if there is a number matches users input in last 10 periods, why I didn’t notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks [@PaulHankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400793/paul-hankin)!**

We can use the TOTP solution which can generate a one-time password every 1 minute, and when we got user’s input, we can check if there’s a TOTP generated in last 10 minutes matches it!